# INOUT port signal is undefined when used as input and output

Tags: vhdl

I have a port signal defined to be and `INOUT` signal.  I set the port to be the output of a D latch and the output is undefined under abnormal circumstances.  When I do not run the output of the D latch through another module, all works fine.  I need to take the output signal, however, from the d latch and use it as an input to a different module.  When this is done, the output from the D latch is ALWAYS undefined.  Below is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity top_level is
    Port ( a_raw : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b_raw : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              a_latched : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              b_latched : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
              load : in STD_LOGIC;
              s : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out0 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out1 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out2 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out3 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out4 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              out5 : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              flag : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
              result : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));

signal numone : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0001";
signal test : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := a_latched;
end top_level;

architecture Structure of top_level is
component fulladdsub
    Port (
    x : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    y : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    cin : in STD_LOGIC;
    sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end component;
component D_Latch
    Port (
    D : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    EN : in STD_LOGIC;
    Q : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end component;  

begin

stage0: D_Latch port map(D=>a_raw, EN=>load, Q=>a_latched);                    -- allows load to stop A,B from changing
stage1: D_Latch port map(D=>b_raw, EN=>load, Q=>b_latched);
--stage2: fulladdsub port map(x=>a_latched, y=>b_latched, cin=>'0', sum=>out0);  -- A+B
--stage3: fulladdsub port map(x=>a_latched, y=>b_latched, cin=>'1', sum=>out1);  -- A-B
stage2: fulladdsub port map(x=>a_latched, y=>numone, cin=>'0', sum=>out2);       -- A+1
--stage5: fulladdsub port map(x=>a_latched, y=>numone, cin=>'1', sum=>out3);        -- A-1
--stage6: fulladdsub port map(x=>b_latched, y=>numone, cin=>'0', sum=>out4);     -- B+1
--stage7: fulladdsub port map(x=>b_latched, y=>numone, cin=>'1', sum=>out5);     -- B-1


end Structure;
```

`b_latched` and `a_latched` are the ports in question here.  When I simulate my code as is, `a_latched` is always undefined (it is used in stage2) and `b_latched` is defined when it should be.  Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you use an inout, your architecture needs to explicitly drive it to `'Z'` when you are trying to use it as an input. Likewise the containing architecture (usually only a testbench for inouts) needs to set its driver to `'Z'` when it wants to read the output.

I can't determine exactly what your problem is, because there isn't enough detail in your question; it is missing the implementations of `D_Latch` and whatever the "another module" is that you are having issues with.

Also bear in mind that if this is for an FPGA target, you should only use `inout` for top level ports that connect to pins on your FPGA. That is typically the only section of the FPGA that has tri-state buffers (what `inout` represents in hardware).

If `D_Latch` is actually written as a latch, then the output will be undefined if you have never asserted the `EN`, as that's what a latch is supposed to do.